# Docker with Java Listening on port and accessing port on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, docker, server, port

I am running my Java-App in a docker container on MacOs.

This Java-App has a web server on the one hand and does database accesses on the other.
The container I am running just contains the Java with the running Jar.
The database is outside the container.

On my host I can access the database 127.0.0.1:5400.

By the setup I tried so far I am not able to access the webserver in the docker.

I would also not know under which address I can access.

I run my docker by:

```
docker run --rm --net=host -v `pwd`/:/mnt -v `pwd`/logs:/logs airdock/oracle-jdk:jdk-8u112 java -jar /mnt/MyJava.jar /mnt/application-localdocker.properties
```

It is configured to listen on port 80. The log states that it startsup well and does listen. As well as the database is connected.

Since I user `--net=host` I was answered that using `-p 9090:80` does not make sense and will not apply. All ports have been exactly passed to the host system. That makes sense.

Nevertheless, after properly starting up the docker container I cannot access `127.0.0.1:80` and I do not see why.

All I want is a listening port (outside to docker-inside) and one accessing port (docker-inside to outside) in my docker container at the same time without bigger fuzz. But that seems not to be provided easily.

This talks about the same: https://forums.docker.com/t/accessing-host-and-exposing-port-same-time-possible-or-not/23914

Comment: the fact that the DB remains outside of a container is a requirement?

Comment: @Nirekim: yes. DB will live somewhere else; I just have an ip address and port to connect to.

Comment: Try it with `-p 80:9090` the first value is usually the host port, Second one the port inside the container. Access to other Urls outside the Container should not be a problem.
[Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

Comment: @springe it starts with __WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode__ I am already having the parameter __--net=host__ on start up. And it does make sense that having __-p x:y__ will be ignored due exposing host ports to inner docker container.... if I got that right, since it says all inner ports are the same as the outer ports...  and isn't it like __-p portOnHost:portWithinDocker__

Comment: oh... so youre running the db on the same host as the docker container and thats why you need the --net-host ?

Comment: The three canonical answers to this sort of question are (a) you're running Docker Toolbox and the "host" network is really a VM's host network; or (b) you're running Docker for Mac and ports below 1024 don't really work; or (c) some other firewall setting is preventing you from reaching the port.  Do any of these apply?

Comment: @springe I am running it --net=host in order t have the in-docker-running-application let connect to the outer world's 127.0.0.1:5400 which in my case is the database. That does work. I would understand: --net=host means outer IP world is shared with the inner-docker world. Which then @'David Maze' would also work. ...still investigating on guessed b) or c)

Comment: I just stumbled over this post: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2716
I states that it simply does not work with macos right now. Do I get that right, could anyone confirm? (I did adjust my question)